# Why can't I omit "apply" in this.apply(_) in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, apply

Observe the following code

```
trait Example {
  type O
  def apply(o: O)
  def f(o: O) = this.apply(o)
}
```

which compiles fine in Scala. I would expect that I can leave out `apply` as usual, writing `def f(o: O) = this(o)`. However, this results in the exciting error message

```
type mismatch;  found   : o.type (with underlying type Example.this.O)
                required: _31.O where val _31: Example
possible cause: missing arguments for method or constructor
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer is incorrect.  You can infer what the actual problem is from the fact that this compiles fine:

```
trait Example {
  def apply(o: String): String = o
  def f(o: String) = this(o)
}
```

this(...) only represents a call to a constructor when the call site is an auxiliary constructor.  The remainder of the time it is a call to apply, just as you imagined.

Comment: sorry, I'm failing to infer what the actual problem is, but I see your point. Could you explain further?

Comment: It's a bug with abstract types.  Notice that the non-compiling example works if you make type O concrete (e.g. "type O = String") or if you make it a type parameter instead (e.g. "trait Example[O]".)

Comment: do you happen to know the issue number for this bug?

Answer (score 11):

You can't because **this()** inside an constructor is a call to this object's constructor (**this()** anywhere else generates a compilation failure) and can not be made into an **apply()** call as it would hide the constructor and make it impossible to call another constructor in your object. **this(args)** is always a call to a constructor method (both in Java and Scala), so when inside your own object, you always have to explicitly call **apply(args)**.

Comment: Huh! Of course, thank you. I was confused about this because in my examples I had an alias for `this` (e.g. `trait Example { f => ... }`), and somehow it's much less obvious that `f(o)` is a call to a constructor.